# React Native - What is the point of using the overflow property for <Image/> component?

Tags: reactjs, css, react-native

According to my knowledge `overflow` property is used to `enable` or `disable` the scrolling in `CSS` or in `CSS type stylingsheet`. Can anyone tell what is the point of using the `overflow` property for `<Image/>` component? A little example will be more appreciated. Thanks !!!

[Reference link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image-style-props#overflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overflow property is used to define actions that will happen if the image goes out of bounds. Say you have a `<div>` with the width or height set to 100px. Inside the `<div>` you have an `<Image>` that is 200px, the image would show out of bounds. If we take overflow:hidden as an example, the image would be cut off at the bounds of the `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

Since an [`<img>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) is an empty element (content: nothing), setting `overflow` on it is, indeed, **pointless**.

But if you look at the output of an `<Image/>` component (what actually gets rendered in the page's source code) you'll notice it's not an `<img>` tag, but a `<div>` tag, and the *"image"* actually gets displayed as the `background-image` of that `<div>`. It can therefore have content.